# Magento 2: How to get the image from salerule?

Tags: magento2, database, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am showing the data of the salerule in the product view and is necessary for me to also show the image and description of the rule.

All the information I need is in Top Banner:

[image]

Is possible get it from the database?